What recourse exists for objectively bad debt consolidation terms?
Alice, a UK citizen living in the UK, has a debt problem.

Alice owes £10,000 to Bob, paying £500 per month and accruing interest at an annual rate of 20%.
Alice owes £5,000 to Carol, paying £250 per month and accruing interest at 20% annually.
Alice owes £5,000 to Dave, paying £250 per month and accruing 20% annual interest.

Alice hears about debt consolidation loans, decides it's a good idea, and applies with a few companies who offer such loans. Most companies refuse because she has bad credit.
Eve, ever the evil one, sees an opportunity to potentially rip off a financially illiterate person, and offers terms so blatantly terrible that no reasonable person who truly understands the terms and their consequences would ever accept:

To start with, Eve charges a £5,000 refinancing fee, increasing the total loan balance to £25,000.
Eve's loan will accrue interest at an annual rate of 100%, compounded monthly, for 8.33% interest per month.
Eve will require a minimum payment each month of £2,500.

Alice, unfamiliar with the importance of certain kinds of terms in financial contracts, accepts Eve's offer. Eve pays off Alice's debts to Bob, Carol, and Dave, and Alice begins paying £2,500 per month to Eve. Despite paying £1,500 more per month than before, she is reducing her remaining balance by £250 less per month than before.
Alice struggles to pay so much per month, but reassures herself that paying off the debt faster will be worth it in the long run. After several months of this, she checks her remaining balance and is shocked and horrified by how little the amount still owed has decreased. Alice finally reads and understands the terms of Eve's loan in full, and realizes how terrible a mistake accepting the loan was.
Alice tries to find another company to take over the loan with better terms, but every company she talks with refuses. She tries to negotiate with Eve for better terms, but Eve is very happy with the loan's terms as is. Eve even threatens legal action if Alice misses a payment.
Alice cannot afford a lawyer, as all of her money is going to living expenses and repaying Eve.
What options, if any, does Alice have for redress against Eve's exploitation of her?

The fact that Eve is offering "objectively worse" loan terms than someone else is not in itself illegal, any more than it would be illegal to sell for you to sell a widget for $2 knowing that I sell them for $1. The unreasonableness of Eve's loan terms may fall afoul of usury or other consumer protection laws, but the simple fact that they're not better than anyone else's isn't illegal. If Eve misrepresents her terms and misleads Alice, there may be an element of fraud.

@NuclearHoagie Loans are typically a regulated industry however, so it can indeed be illegal if the loan terms breach the regulatory regime. E.g. see here for a somewhat related example.

@JBentley Right, that's what I said. Eve's fees and interest rates might be illegal if they are deemed "unreasonably high" by lending laws. But they're not illegal simply by virtue of being worse than Bob's fees and rates.

the terms offered by Eve are illegal, the fact that her terms are bad not.

@NuclearHoagie Ok, I'd misunderstood what you wrote. However, the question isn't about whether Eve's fees were worse than Bob's, it was about them being "objectively bad". If we take "objectively bad" to mean "bad to the extent that it breaches regulatory requirements" then the fact of being bad can be illegal. Granted that "objectively bad" wouldn't be the test that the courts would apply.

@NuclearHoagie Even if Eve's terms are within the legal limits for loan terms in general, the facts that a) it is a debt consolidation loan, and b) its terms are worse than those of the existing loans in every way, make Eve's offer actively counterproductive for its express purpose. Eve's loan product exists for the purpose of improving people's financial situations, but it makes Alice's financial situation strictly worse. Eve cannot claim ignorance of the existing loans because Eve pays off those loans directly - Alice never actually gets the money herself. Does none of that matter?

@JBentley "Objectively bad" for the purpose of this question is intended to mean that the terms make the loan actively counterproductive for its express supposed purpose. As a debt consolidation loan used solely to pay off other loans for the purpose of improving the borrower's financial situation, with payment given directly to the other creditors to ensure that restriction on its use, its purpose is to improve the financial situation of the borrower. With Eve's terms, it instead makes Alice's financial situation strictly worse than before.
